# Flask: Cannot Decode Incoming JSON Submitted Using Requests

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I'm having an issue trying to decode a python dictionary sent to my server as json.
This is what I  have in my application:

```
payload = {'status':[bathroomId,item,percentage,timestamp]}
r=requests.post(url,None,json.dumps(payload))
```

Here is what I do in my Flask server:

```
req = request.get_json()
print req['status']
```

When I try to print the content of `req['status']`, it seems like python won't recognize it as a dictionary and I get an internal server error.

I tried printing `req`, and I get `None`

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried, still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in your request, **Flask will not attempt to decode any JSON found in your request body**.

Instead, `get_json` will return `None` (which is what you're seeing right now).

So, you need to set the `Content-Type` header in your request.

Fortunately [since version 2.4.2 (released a year ago)](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/8f17741849edb5e7eba0356f90cb17e43c938a2f), requests has a helper argument to post JSON; this will set the proper headers for you. Use:

```
requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Alternatively (e.g. using requests < 2.4.2), you can set the header yourself:

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

---

Here is the relevant code from Flask:

- Flask [only loads JSON if `is_json` is `True`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/805692108ae973281d793250ca883cc1412ab08d/flask/wrappers.py#L142-L143) (or if you pass `force=True` to `get_json`). Otherwise, it returns `None`.
- [`is_json` looks at the `Content-Type` header](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/805692108ae973281d793250ca883cc1412ab08d/flask/wrappers.py#L118-L123), and looks for `application/json` there.

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo Were you unable to use `json=...`? If so, you might want to upgrade `requests`: 2.4.2 is a year old.